# Is there any possible way to take scroll position and don't get error that element is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have animation that triggers when my scroll position is same as position of element that I want to animate. After scroll to some position, I refresh page and get error that element that i want to animate is not defined. This is code that I am using for animation:

```
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
       var element = $element.find(".pr-bemax-bodyOfBagger");
       if (this.pageYOffset >= element.offset().top - 400) {
          var myEl = $element.find("#bulldozer-hand");
          myEl[0].classList.add('bulldozer-hand');
       }
    });
```

P.S. I don't want to use $timeout.

Comment: Where is this code being executed at?

Comment: I have controller for this code and that controller is part of app.js and that app.js. I have one index.html for all controllers and directives and they are connected with ui-sref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just defend against the fact `offset` will return `undefined` if the set you call it on is empty:

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
   var element = $element.find(".pr-bemax-bodyOfBagger");
   var offset = element.offset(); // <===
   if (offset && this.pageYOffset >= offset.top - 400) {
   //  ^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^
      var myEl = $element.find("#bulldozer-hand");
      myEl[0].classList.add('bulldozer-hand');
   }
});
```

Comment: So if I set something like this:

if(element !=  undefined){
     // do something
}

This is not working

Comment: @VeselinKontić: Have another look at the code above. `element` will never be `undefined` (assuming that this code is using jQuery, as it appears to be). `element` may refer to an *empty jQuery object* (an empty set). If it does, `offset` will return `undefined`. The code above then uses a guard (`if (offset && ...`) to guard against trying to use `.top` on `undefined`.